# Asking a question where there's a duplicate with lots of answers that don't answer the question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, duplicate-question

So I asked a [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47340/correct-term-for-stacked-super-justified-text) which is basically a duplicate of [another question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/what-is-the-name-for-making-words-equal-in-length) - but none of the answers to that other question answer the question.

Confused? I am.

What should I do? The other answers are basically a selection of basic typographical terms - clearly people find them useful, but they don't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to **edit** the original question adding more detail than it is to post the same essential question.

Editing bumps the question to the top again so it'll get attention even though it's older.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Scott's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19499/23061) on the other question is a valid one that answers the question being asked. I do think the questions are asking the same thing and have flagged it to be closed as a duplicate as such.

Speaking generally, the best practice is to not re-ask questions that have already been asked regardless of the answers there. If the question is the same, another one doesn't have to be asked.

This is one of the reasons why bounties were added to SE sites - to encourage better answers for questions that haven't received enough attention. I think one would be perfect for this situation.